# Error getmypalletrack() if-else-function typeID cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: anylogic

I would like to store my pallets into my pallet racks if the set conditions of my function are true. After I did my parameter `typeID` with the type int into my arguments it says `typeID` cannot be resolved to a variable. `getmyPalletRack(typeID)`
After I changed `getmyPalletRack(typeID)` to `getmyPalletRack()` it says that the method `getmyPalletRack(int)` in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments ().
I get my typeIDs from the database I attached. They are connected with my source block so that isn't the problem. Agent is Pallet.
The problem could be that I the variable typeID cannot be resolved but I don't know how to solve that problem.
[image: function]

[image: rackstore]

[image: dbase]

Comment: agent.typeID maybe?

Comment: Oh Felipe thank you very much! That was the problem. Agent with type Pallet is the right argument and then agent.typeID into the function.